# How to create "Volumemesh" from closed "surfacemesh"?

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

Given a surface region (`MesgRegion netz2D`), for example

```
bild = RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, Mesh -> All];
netz2D = DiscretizeGraphics [bild]  (* mesh region*)
RegionDimension[netz2D] (*2*)
```

[image]

Question: How to mesh the volume defined by the meshregion `netz2D`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I expect the following to work only in a few cases. It works here.

Extract the polygons and re-make them into a `BoundaryMeshRegion`:

```
bm = BoundaryMeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[netz2D], MeshCells[netz2D, 2]]
```

Then you can triangulate the interior:

```
TriangulateMesh[bm]
```

A better way to achieve the same would have been:

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}]
```

The important thing is to keep surface meshes as `BoundaryMeshRegion`s, not as `MeshRegion`s. This way we maintain information about the interior.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll test it. Does `BoundaryMeshRegion` always create a closed surface?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes, I believe that is the point. For this to work, all the polygons must be oriented the same way, and they should share vertices and edges. Otherwise the construction will fail.

Comment: @  Szabolcs I tried to reproduce your suggestions but didn't succeed. MMA 11.0.1 cann't evaluate `Volume[bm]` and  `RegionEmbeddingDimension[bm]` . Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Seems to work here ... http://i.stack.imgur.com/iklAs.png ... what did you try exactly? Also work with the `bm` obtained using the first code line in my post.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I tried the first two code lines of your answer (based on netz2D)

Comment: I mean to say also *works* (the s went missing). I'm not sure what the difference might be ... the OS? http://i.stack.imgur.com/p8UYZ.png

Comment: Obviously the OS. Sorry I don't know how to show my png as you did. In my try `bm=... ` isn't evaluated `(*BoundaryMeshRegion[..]*)`.

Comment: @Ulrich It is possible that the polygons are not ordered (oriented) consistently, and this is why it fails. This is what I was thinking of when I said it might only work in a few cases.  It is strange though that this would be the case on one OS but not the other.

Comment: @ Szabolcs If the 3D-Region-object lies completely in the coordinate-space it works. Again thank you for your support.

Answer (score 4):

```
bild2 = DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, 
  {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}], 
  MeshCellStyle -> {{2, All} -> Opacity[.5]}]
```

[image]

```
RegionDimension[bild2]
```

> 3

Answer (score 4):

Depending a bit on what you want to do you could use the FEM mesh, that can be made more accurate than a `DiscretizeRegion` approach.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
reg = ImplicitRegion[
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}];
bild2 = ToElementMesh[reg, "ImproveBoundaryPosition" -> True];
vol = \[Pi]/6;
vol - Total[bild2["MeshElementMeasure"], 2]
6.633774715880669`*^-6
vol - RegionMeasure[DiscretizeRegion[reg]]
0.0004287579660063878`
```

For 3D the Automatic setting for "ImproveBoundaryPosition" is False (for 2D it is True) and with this improved boundary you get a much more accurate representation of the region. This is useful if you want to numerically solve PDEs or integrate over the region.

Also note that the workflow for `ElementMesh` is more intuitive as the boundary mesh can be made to a full mesh:

```
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[reg];
ToElementMesh[bmesh];
```

If you want the same accuracy as above you'd use `ToNumericalRegion` to connect the region and the boundary mesh.

You can think of a `BoundaryMeshRegion` as a sparse representation of a full region. A boundary element mesh is different; it is a representation of the boundary of the region. As a consequence you can do this:

```
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {Pi/6, 3 Pi/4}]];

NIntegrate[1, Element[{x, y}, bmesh]]
1.8323249230952223`
```

But not this:

```
ToElementMesh[bmesh]
$Failed
```

Note that if the boundary is closed

```
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[Circle[{0, 0}, 1]];
```

Then `ToElementMesh` will generate a full mesh.

```
Head[ToElementMesh[bmesh]]
ElementMesh
```

To get to your question, that's why this works:

```
ToElementMesh[RegionBoundary[netz2D]]

bild2 = ToElementMesh[
   ImplicitRegion[
    x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}]];
```

Look at the wire frame of the surface elements:

```
bild2["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Look at the wire frame of the full mesh:

```
bild2["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "MeshElements"]]
```

[image]
Or if you want a MeshRegion:

```
MeshRegion[ToElementMesh[RegionBoundary[netz2D], "MeshOrder" -> 1]]
```

Comment: @ user21 :Thank you very much for your detailed answer. In my special problem I tried to create a "volumemesh" from the surfacepoints which I got from `RegionPlot3D`. Just one question: `bild2`seems to be a 3D-mesh, but `bild2["Wireframe"]` only shows surface elements?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, added an example that show how to get the full wire frame mesh.

Comment: @ user21 Tricky, where  did you find the options `"Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "MeshElements"]` of "Wireframe"?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, you can find such information in the [ElementMesh visualization tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshVisualization.html)

Comment: Thanks for your support!